# Defining conic problems over some specific cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

I am working with the following definition for conic optimization problems (based on Alexander Barvinok's book "A Course in Convexity"):

Let $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{Y}$ be Euclidean spaces, let $K\subseteq\mathbb{E}$ and  $L\subseteq\mathbb{Y}$ both be proper cones, let $c\in\mathbb{E}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Y}$, and consider a linear function $A\colon\mathbb{E}\to\mathbb{Y}$ .

A conic optimization problem over $K$ is defined as:

$$\inf\{\langle x,c\rangle\, \colon A(x)\succeq_{_L^{\ast}} b , x\in K \}.$$

However, I am having trouble defining conic problems over a specific cone. For example, i have the following definition for SOCP (which are conic problems over $\mathbb{L}_n=\{x\oplus t\in\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}_+\,\colon\|x\|\leq t\}$):

Let $\mathbb{Y}$ be a Euclidean space, let $K\subseteq\mathbb{Y}$ be a proper cone, and consider $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{L}_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}$.  Also let a linear function $A\colon\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Y}$.

A second order conic problem (SOCP) is defined as:
$$\inf\{\langle x,c\rangle\, \colon A(x)\succeq_{_K^{\ast}} b , x\in \mathbb{L}_n \}.$$

I see that my definition does not correspond to the definition of, for example, Wikipedia, because there is no 'extra' cone $K$ in other definitions. Where is the flaw with my definition? How could I correct it?

Comment: I do not see the problem. $(L,K)$ in your first problem is $(K,\mathbb{L}_n)$ in the second problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your question is about converting your SOCO problem with conic inequalities to the notation on Wikipedia with equality constraints. You can simply add an additional variable:
$$Ax \succeq_{_K} b, \quad x \in L $$
is equivalent to:
$$Ax - b = y, \quad (x,y) \in L \times K. $$
Note that $L \times K$ is a cone when $L$ and $K$ are cones.

Comment: If I undestood correctly, you are saying that my problem is equivalent to some conic problem over $K\times L$. But then any SOCP is a problem over $\mathbb{L}_n\times K$ for any proper cone $K$?

Comment: $K$ needs to be a second order cone (or a product of those) for the problem to be called SOCO.

Comment: In this case, is the following definition correct?

Consider $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{L}_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{L}_m\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m\oplus\mathbb{R}_+$.  Also let a linear function $A\colon\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^m\oplus\mathbb{R}_+$. 

A second order conic problem (SOCP) is defined as 
$\inf\{\langle x,c\rangle\, \colon A(x)\geq_{_\mathbb{L}_m^{\ast}} b , x\in \mathbb{L}_n \}.$

Comment: That is indeed a SOCO problem. However, your definition is rather limited because the constraints are formulated with just one second order cone, so it cannot have two linear inequalities (just to name an example).